# Flask Socket application deployment using nginx and gunicorn in Ubuntu 22.04 is not working. Getting 404 error from nginx

Tags: python, sockets, nginx, flask

When I run the below code from a local Ubuntu machine, the socket connection is successfully established; however, when I deploy it to an Ubuntu server, it does not work.

This is the error message I received from Nginx.

```
- [28/Dec/2022:07:29:10 +0000] "GET /media HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "Boost.Beast/266" "3.235.111.201"
```

Linux is running and I check the IP it is 200 and the application also is running.

The code is in the file `aap.py`

```
import json
import logging
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_sockets import Sockets
from gevent import pywsgi
from geventwebsocket.handler import WebSocketHandler
import os
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
sockets = Sockets(app)


@app.route("/hello", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello():
    print("testing")
    return jsonify({"message": "Success"})


@sockets.route('/test')
def test(ws):
    print(f"*****Test****{ws}")


@sockets.route('/media')
def echo(ws):
    print(f"Media WS: {ws}")
    while True:
        message = ws.receive()
        packet = json.loads(message)
        print(packet)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    file_handler = RotatingFileHandler('log_data.log', maxBytes=10000, backupCount=2)
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logging.basicConfig(handlers=[file_handler], level=logging.DEBUG)
    logger = logging.getLogger('log_data.log')
    app.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    server = pywsgi.WSGIServer(('127.0.0.1', 5000), app, handler_class=WebSocketHandler)
    #server = pywsgi.WSGIServer(('', 5000), app, handler_class=WebSocketHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```

from the localhost, I run the command `python3 app.py`
Here is the screenshot of the terminal and socket connection test result.

[image: localhost python running]

[image: client socket connection success]

My nginx config is in file  `/etc/nginx/sites-available/test-socket` and the content is:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
      }
    }
```

I am running one service file `/etc/systemd/system/demo.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve testApp
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/root/test-socket
Environment="PATH=/root/test-socket/myenv/bin"
ExecStart=/root/test-socket/myenv/bin/gunicorn --worker-class eventlet -w1 --workers 3 --bind 127.0.0.1:5000 app:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

[image: Application is running]

Comment: Are you abble to resolve that URL when you run it locally?

Comment: Looking at https://gist.github.com/punchagan/53600958c1799c2dcf26 I can say that `socket.io` in URL is wrong. It should be `/test`

Comment: @shiv yes I am able to connect the socket in the local host.  I removed the socket.io location still/hello API is working and /test is not working.